# SwiftUI Observable Object Not Observed

Tags: swift, xcode, crash, observable, swiftui

In my latest project to learn SwiftUI, I create an Observable Object in a file called UserData:

```
final class UserData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data = jsonData
}
```

I set the Environmental Variable in SceneDelgate:

```
window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: dataList().environmentObject(UserData()))
```

And declare it in the relevant file:

```
@EnvironmentObject private var userData: UserData

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(userData.data) { data in
                    DataRow(data: data)
                }
            }
        }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("My Data"))
    }
```

Yet I get this:

"Can Not Preview File, Data.app may have crashed"

Checking the crash report, it appears my code can't find UserData. However, I believe I have taken all the steps necessary to make it observable (as this is basically copy and pasted from an Apple tutorial). What's going wrong?

Comment: What is the type of jsonData ?

Comment: Something is wrong with your jsonData.

Comment: Please provide full source code what is JsonData we can not decide

Comment: use  "@ObservedObject"  instead of "@EnvironmentObject" might work

Answer (score 1):

When using `EnvironmentObject` and you want to test in the live preview, you need to set the object manually like this:

```
struct dataList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        dataList().environmentObject(UserData()) // Your env object
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be crash in your real time preview

```
  struct dataList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        dataList().environmentObject(UserData())
    }
}
```